# How to Add Harmonics to Sine Waves

Tags: c++, signal-processing

Without posting the entire header and cpp files I have some code here that generates sine waves:

```
void CAudioGenerate::GenereateSinewave() 
{
   if(!GenerateBegin())
      return;

   short audio[2];

   for(double time=0.;  time < m_duration;  time += 1. / m_sampleRate)
   {                 
      audio[0] = short(m_amplitude * sin(time * 2 * M_PI * m_freq1));
      audio[1] = short(m_amplitude * sin(time * 2 * M_PI * m_freq1));

      GenerateWriteFrame(audio);

// Progress
      if(!GenerateProgress(time / m_duration))
         break;
   }


   // Close generator
   GenerateEnd();
}
```

I want to add some harmonics that reduce the amplitude by 1/2, 1/3, and 1/4. I think that I have to change m_amplitude but I'm not entirely sure which is the correct way.

I thought about adding `m_amplitude = m_amplitude*(1/time)` but that didn't work.

Comment: This seems to be a math question more than a programming one.

Comment: I know next to nothing about signal processing, but can't you do it by generating two waves, and adding (or subtracting) them? See e.g. [this image](http://www.doctronics.co.uk/images/sig_18.gif) (on how to generate square wave, but could be used to generate any kind of shape I guess).

Comment: I've done a little signal processing, and I don't know how harmonics (sounds at different frequencies) would consistently affect your amplitude.  Different frequencies would be additive and subtractive at different points.

Comment: I made an image of a 2f harmonic, and show how the amplitude gets bigger, and smaller at the same time:
http://i.imgur.com/Sc89xMo.jpg

Comment: Now.. if you and two sounds at the same frequency with an inverted sync... the second inverted sound being a smaller amplitude, you would effectively get a reduced amplitude... but in code - why not just make your m_amplitude smaller?

Comment: Yes, you were right, it does have to do with the frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Harmonics are unrelated in *amplitude*. Instead, a harmonic is a wave that has `N=2,3,4...`  times the *frequency*. Mixing the different waves is just a matter of adding the components.

Thus, for two harmonics the code is:

```
audio[0] = short(m_amplitude[0] * sin(time * 2 * M_PI * m_freq1))
         + short(m_amplitude[1] * sin(time * 4 * M_PI * m_freq1))
         + short(m_amplitude[2] * sin(time * 6 * M_PI * m_freq1));
```

Comment: Don't the trig functions start to lose accuracy as you get further from 2*pi? You might find a phase error creeping in as time progresses.

Comment: True. At around sin(2^55) you can't have any accuracy at all. I suspect this isn't a major problem if you're still struggling with basic trig. If I would need to come up with a method to fix this, I'd probably go hardcore math : `sin(x+dx)=sin x cos dx + cos x sin dx; 
 cos(x+dx)=cos x cos dx - sin x sin dx`. You can incrementally calculate `sin(x+dx)` by keeping track of `sin(x)` as well as `cos(x)`. You still have some rounding errors creep in, so you may need to normalize to `sin(x)^2 + cos(x)^2 = 1`. But you just need an accurate `sin(dx)` here, which typically is _very_ accurate.

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct. Any reason why you used 4 and 6?

Comment: @ratman2050: The first harmonic has the double frequency, so `2 * (2 * M_PI * m_freq1)` = `4 * ...`, and the second has `3 * ( 2 * M_PI * ...`